# Calculation of sum of orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If we add for $i=1,..n$ these equations
\begin{align}
\notag
g(Y,A_{Z}e_{i})e_{i}-g(e_{i},A_{Z}e_{i})Y=-g(e_{i},Z)A_{e_{i}}Y + g(Y,e_{i})A_{Z}e_{i}-g(e_{i},e_{i})A_{Z}Y
\end{align}
is it true that we get
\begin{align}
\notag
(n+1)A_{Z}Y=0,
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\notag
nA_{Z}Y=0?
\end{align}
I found this in one paper, maybe it is just typo. I want to be sure.
Also, here $A$ satisfies $A_{Z}Y=A_{Y}Z$ for any two vectors, and $e_{i}$'s, $i=1,..,n$ are orthonormal vectors.

Comment: gee, and what is $g$? Also, it seems to be that it does not really matter whether $n$ or $n+1$ since both says that $A_ZY=0$ anyway.

Comment: $g$ is a metric. yes it does not matter, I just wanted to be sure. :)